# ¿Cómo mostrar positivos e impares en PHP?

Tags: php, bucle-for, números-enteros

Ya estoy en el ciclo `for`:

> El problema es el siguiente:
>
> Leer *5 números* e imprimir cuántos son *positivos*, cuántos *negativos* y cuántos neutros.

La lógica la entiendo bien y ya lo he hecho en *Pseudocódigo*, sin embargo, no logro entender cómo aplicarlo bien en *PHP*.

Así lo he hecho yo:

Primero el archivo *PHP* con el *HTML*:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h3> Leer 5 números e imprimir cuántos son positivos, cuántos negativos y cuántos neutros.</h3>
        <br />
        <form method="POST" action="ciclo1.php">
 <?php
    for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
        echo "Digite numero $i = <input type='text' name=n$i />
            <br />";
    }
?>
            <input type="submit" value="Validar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Luego el *PHP* con la resolucion del problema (que no ha dado nada):

```
    for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++){

        $positivo=0;
        $negativo=0;

        if($i>0){
            Echo "<br>los positivos son".$i;
        }elseif ($i<0){
            echo "los negativos son ".$i;   
        }else {
            echo "Es igual a O".$i;
        }
    }
?>
```

Cuando lo ejecuto solo me muestra la lista ordenada, pero no los números que ingresa el usuario. Con la resolución de este problema entendería los otros.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. ¿Positivos negativos y neutros? En el título también pone impares. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y hacerla concisa? Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los campos enviados por el formulario a través del método POST te llegarán en la variable `$_POST`, por lo que deberás iterar por ella y, además, iniciar las variables ANTES del bucle y no dentro de éste y, finalmente, mostrar el resultado al final del bucle y no dentro de él.

Un ejemplo funcional:

```
<?php
$positivo = 0;
$negativo = 0;
$neutro = 0;
/* Iteramos por cada campo POST recibido */
foreach($_POST as $clave => $valor) {
  /* Convertimos el valor (que se entrega como cadena) a entero */
  $i = intval($valor);
  if ($i > 0) {
    $positivo++;
  } elseif ($i < 0) {
    $negativo++;
  } else {
    $neutro++;
  }
}
?><ul>
  <li>Positivos: <?= $positivos ?></li>
  <li>Negativos: <?= $negativos ?></li>
  <li>Neutros: <?= $neutros ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias. Se me había olvidado incluirlo en el POST...y bueno casi todo lo demás que publicaste jaja, pero al menos tenia yo un poco la idea jeje. De nuevo muchas gracias. Ahora a seguir practicando.

Comment: ¡Ánimo! Empezar es duro, pero luego la cosa mejora 

Answer (score 1):

lo primero de todo, mucho ánimo, todos hemos empezado!!
Si lo que realmente quieres es saber cuantos hay positivos, negativos y neutros lo que tienes que hacer es declarar variables para cada caso. Ejemplo:

```
$contadorPositivo = 0;
$contadorNegativo = 0
$contadorNeutro = 0;
```

Una vez que tienes eso, tienes que incrementar la varible cada vez que cumpla su condición. Reutilizando tu código sería algo así:

```
if($i>0){
   $contadorPositivo++;    
}

else if ($i<0){
   $contadorNegativo++;   
}

else {
   $contadorNeutro++;
}
```

Comment: Deberías cambiar `contadorNeutro` por `$contadorNeutro`. Las variables en PHP van precedidas siempre por el signo dólar (`$`). Además, no solucionas su problema, que es el de iterar por los campos enviados por el formulario.

Comment: Ahora te quedaría lo de iterar por los campos del formulario :)

Comment: cierto, ya está corregido. Gracias.

Comment: Aún te queda lo de iterar por los campos del formulario ;)